# Why div containing img does not stretch his parent's div height

Tags: html, css, image

I wonder why `mainCountainerHeadLogo` does not stretch parent div `mainCountainerHead` **height**?

If I scale the page, both `mainCountainerHeadTitle` and `mainCountainerHeadMenu` stretch `mainCountainerHead` just fine.

Sorry for my english and thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/gvcs0r6b/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.mainCountainer {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.mainCountainerHead {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: auto;
}
.mainCountainerHeadLogo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.mainCountainerHeadLogo img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: -50%;
  right: -50%;
  bottom: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  margin: auto
}
.mainCountainerHeadTitle{
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 3%;
}
.mainCountainerHeadMenu{
  margin-left: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 2%;
  text-align: center;
}
.mainLink {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
.mainLinkButton {
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
.mainLinkButton:hover {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
.mainLinkDropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
.dropdownContent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 30px;
  min-width: 130px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 10;
}
.dropdownContent a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.mainLinkDropdown:hover .dropdownContent{
  display: block;
}
.dropdownContent a:hover{
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainCountainer">
 <div class="mainCountainerHead">
    <div class="mainCountainerHeadLogo">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/cYzWJFM/logo-Copy.jpg" title="logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="mainCountainerHeadTitle">
      <h4>Welcome aboard!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="mainCountainerHeadMenu">
      <div class="mainLink">
        <button class="mainLinkButton">Main</button>
      </div>
      <div class="mainLinkDropdown">
        <button class="mainLinkButton">Dropdown</button>
        <div class="dropdownContent">
          <a href="">Link 1</a>
          <a href="">Link 2</a>
          <a href="">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mainLink">
        <button class="mainLinkButton">Contacts</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## In answer to your question:

That's because the `float` property puts the HTML elements out of the normal page flow, and this causes what you're experiencing. Its effect is similar to `position: absolute` which is to move the element to "a different layer".

## How to solve it?

Well... there are a lot of ways to achieve what you want, and almost all of them requires to refactorize your code. Actually, you have a lot of code that makes it difficult to achieve your goal. You should get rid of `float` and start using other technics like Flexbox.

I could show you a solution if you provide a sketch of the layout you want.

Comment: Yes, flexbox is the best option here and will probably cut your code in half. You also have height set to 100px on the logo parent which would further prevent it from growing.

Answer (score 0):

change the CSS for img to this

```
.mainCountainerHeadLogo img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: auto
}
```